# Only allow .click event if window size below certain number

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, screen-size

I have a `#div1`, which when clicked should toggle `#div2` with jquery. This click event should only execute the function if the window size is below 760px. I'm bad at javascript so I'm getting wrong results... Instead of toggling the div when the user clicks on the `#div1`, it toggles itself on, when you resize the window below 760px.
I'm sure there's something obvious wrong with the order of the if-statement or something.

That's my code:

```
$(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 760){
        $('#div').click(function(){
                $('#div2').toggle({"display":"block"});
        });
    }
});
```

Hope my question is okay to understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your order is a little mixed up. It should be

```
$(function(){
    $('#div').click(function(){
        if($(window).width() <= 760){
                $('#div2').toggle({"display":"block"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: funny thing is that I even had tried it like that before, and it behaved the exact same way :) Still acts like that. it triggers when I'm resizing the window...

Comment: Do you have a working example of the problem? Like a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't. I'll rethink my whole approach. Maybe there's another way :)

Comment: I just returned to my aforementioned 'problem'... and found the reason for it... I'm not going to go into detail here, but basically it was because I had another js function toggling the element on window *resize*. that other function was actually meant for a set of other elements but I had put the wrong selector in there by mistake. Well, gotta pay more attention. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: I want to delete the event on window.resize. That would be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put the if inside the .click() ?

```
$(function(){
   $('#div').click(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 760)
      {
         $('#div2').toggle({"display":"block"});
      }
   });
});
```

Hope it helps!